# Terraform: GKE Cluster with Nodes in different zones

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine, terraform-provider-gcp

I have this Terraform GKE cluster with 3 nodes. When I deploy this cluster all nodes are localised in the same zones which is `europe-west1-b`.

`gke-cluster.yml`

```yaml
resource "google_container_cluster" "primary" {
  name = var.cluster_name

  initial_node_count       = var.initial_node_count

  master_auth {
    username = ""
    password = ""

    client_certificate_config {
      issue_client_certificate = false
    }
  }

  node_config {
    //machine_type = "e2-medium"
    oauth_scopes = [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring",
    ]

    metadata = {
      disable-legacy-endpoints = "true"
    }

    labels = {
      app = var.app_name
    }

    tags = ["app", var.app_name]
  }

  timeouts {
    create = "30m"
    update = "40m"
  }
}
```

`variables.tf`

```yaml
variable "cluster_name" {
  default = "cluster"
}

variable "app_name" {
  default = "my-app"
}

variable "initial_node_count" {
  default = 3
}

variable "kubernetes_min_ver" {
  default = "latest"
}

variable "kubernetes_max_ver" {
  default = "latest"
}

variable "remove_default_node_pool" {
  default = false
}

variable "project" {
  default = "your-project-name"
}

variable "credentials" {
  default = "terraform-key.json"
}

variable "region" {
  default = "europe-west1"
}

variable "zone" {
  type        = list(string)
  description = "The zones to host the cluster in."
  default     = ["europe-west1-b", "europe-west1-c", "europe-west1-d"]
}
```

And would like to know if it's possible to deploy each node in a different zone.
If yes how can I do it using Terraform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add the following line

```
resource "google_container_cluster" "primary" {
  name = "cluster"
  location = "us-central1"
  initial_node_count       = "3"
```

in order to create a [regional cluster](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/regional-clusters). The above will bring up 9 nodes with each zone (f a b) containing 3 nodes. If you only want 1 node per zone, then just change initial_node_count to 1.

More info [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/container_cluster#argument-reference) at Argument reference.