# Error when using Terraform Plan and Google Provider "Cannot determine region"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

When I do a 'terraform plan', I get the following error:

> │ Error: Cannot determine region: set in this resource, or set provider-level 'region' or 'zone'.
> │ 
> │ 
> │ Error: Cannot determine region: set in this resource, or set provider-level 'region' or 'zone'.
> │ 
> │ 
> Operation failed: failed running terraform plan (exit 1)

My provider looks like this

```
provider "google" { 
  project = "test" 
  region = "europe-west2" 
  zone = "europe-west2-c"
}
```

An example of a resource is

```
resource "google_bigquery_dataset" "test" {
  location = "EU"
  dataset_id = "test"
  friendly_name = "test"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for Terraform for "zone" should be "zones".  Moreover, the value should be a list in square brackets "[]".  Here is an example of what you could try:

```
zones = ["europe-west2-a", "europe-west2-b", "europe-west2-c"]
```

These two postings have default settings for zones that can be illustrative:

https://admintuts.net/server-admin/provision-kubernetes-clusters-in-gcp-with-terraform/

[Terraform: GKE Cluster with Nodes in different zones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64633645/terraform-gke-cluster-with-nodes-in-different-zones)

(But you do not need a "default" assignment to minimally get your Terraform for GKE to work; you need to use the "zones" keyword)

Comment: No, not in the provider.  Provider should be just `zone`.  See provider [reference](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/provider_reference) docs

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while trying to update composer version, the new composer was corrupted (state was tainted in the state file) and by removing the composer instance from the console and from state file I was able to do plan and apply correctly, try to double check your resources and their state in the state file.